# jQuery $.ajax to pass multidimensional array to PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, multidimensional-array

I am using jQuery and PHP to write JSON data to my server. I'm processing a decent amount of repeating numeric data (~.75kb), so I want to pass the data to PHP in the form of a multidimensional array.

At the moment I cannot manage to get the data to PHP in a form that it can recognize. I've tried various combinations of sending/receiving as arrays and objects with no success.

The best case scenario would be one in which I pass a the array to the PHP and the PHP converts it to a readable form. I'd rather not use associative arrays or any serializing on the part of the Javascript.

Code... This is giving me a 500 internal server error, which no longer occurs if I omit the passed data variable. (I'm not yet using $data in the php file yet because I know it's not working.)

```
function generateData() {
  // code here
  return [ one[ sub_one[], sub_two[] ], two[], three[], four[] /* Etc... */ ]
}
function saveData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/save.php",
        data: {
            "area":"testing",
            "location":"testing",
            "name":"testing",
            "data":generateData()
        }
    });
}
```

```
<?php
    $area = $_GET['area'];
    $location = $_GET['location'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $data = $_GET['data']);

    # Performing operations with variables...

    echo 1;
?>
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: you got one extra bracket: $data = $_GET['data']);  <--

Comment: So I do... The 500 internal server error is gone, and I'm getting $data now. I'll try dumping $data and see if I can access any of it.

Comment: You should pass your data as JSON.

Comment: JSON can be accessed as an associative array in PHP, so why take an extra step to serialize JSON and pass it to the PHP to format it for my file when I can do this in a single step?

Comment: Short comment, you can't **send** objects over the web. Not from javascript to php, not from my pc to yours, there always needs to be some sort of serializing and deserializing involved, however, in your case jQuery and PHP takes care for that for you :).

Comment: Obviously it all comes down to bits eventually, but this method requires the fewest steps to use the data in both languages as an understood datatype.

Comment: The use of http get to update info is inconsistent with the http standard and dangerous. You should be using http post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
"data": {
    data: generateCellData()
}
```

The above code passes data as an object to PHP, whereby I can access the original array as $data("data"). I'm still somewhat baffled by why this works when I'm already passing the data and other parameters as an object.